# How a password prompt come when user try to stop windows service c#

Tags: c#, windows-services

Basically I want to develop a win service password protected. I want that when user try to stop windows service then a password will be required. If I develop a separate win app and write the code in win service stop event and from there I will invoke that password apps which will ask for password to stop the service. Is it possible?

```
protected override void OnStop()
{
    password p = new password();
    if (p.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
    {

    }
}
```

I know that we can not start win form apps from win service. Please guide me how to design this kind of win service using C#. Thanks

Comment: You really don't want to do this; permissions on who should be able to stop / start services should be handled at the OS level, preferably through a local or AD group.